# why N is slower when setting precision

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

```
Column[{
N[Sin[1] + Cos[1], 5] // AbsoluteTiming,
N[Sin[1] + Cos[1]] // AbsoluteTiming
}]
```

```
{0.000073,1.3818}
{0.000015,1.38177}
```

I guess it's related to something like [performance between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426165/is-using-double-faster-than-float)

Comment: when using `N[num,n]` you get arbitrary precision number. When using  `N[num]` you get machine precision number. Obviously the arbitrary precision will be slower since it requires software and not just hardware.

Comment: from manual https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html

The main advantage of using the built‐in floating‐point capabilities of your computer is speed. Arbitrary‐precision numerical calculations, which do not make such direct use of these capabilities, are usually many times slower than machine‐precision calculations.

Comment: @Nasser Wrong. Sin and Cos are implemented in software in glibc, because Intel really managed to ruin the HW instruction precision. It was a giant scandal. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/

Comment: Library code using hardware arithmetic will still beat code that uses software bignum arithmetic.